# Iterator with find() in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator, find, stdvector

I want to know how to get the position of the result when I use the find() command.

My code have the command:

```
vector<int>::iterator result = find(list_of_number.begin(), list_of_number.end(), number_need_to_find);
    cout << result;
```

And it give me the error as follow:

```
error: invalid cast from type 'std::vector<int>::iterator' to type 'int'
   57 |     cout << (int)result;
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Good news! Unlike other containers, vector iterators in C++ have superpowers: you can do some simple math with them. Pop quiz: do you know what do you get when you subtract `begin()` from a valid iterator to the same vector?

Comment: `std::distance(list_of_number.begin(), result)`

Comment: For a vector iterator you can just subtract (same as with pointers) `cout << (result - list_of_number.begin())`.

Comment: You should get out of the habit of thinking that casting is the solution to whatever problem you have, it almost never is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. The [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) returns the iterator pointing to the element if it has been found, otherwise, it returns the end iterator. Therefore a check needs to be done prior to using the iterator `result`.

Secondly, the

```
std::cout << result;
```

trying to print the iterator itself. You should have instead checked the iterator for `list_of_number.end()` and (if found) use [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) to find the position of the found element in the `list_of_number`.

```
#include <iterator>   // std::distance

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> list_of_number{1, 2, 3, 4};

    // if init-statement since C++17
    if (auto iter = std::find(
        list_of_number.cbegin(), list_of_number.cend(), 3); // find the element using std::find
        iter != list_of_number.cend())                      // if found (i.e. iter is not the end of vector iterator)
    {
        std::cout << std::distance(list_of_number.cbegin(), iter); // use  std::distance for finding the position
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Not found\n";
    }
}
```